# How can I generate sequence values of mixed letter characters and number digits in FactoryBot?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sequence, factory-bot, digits

I need to generate sequences of labels that look like "ABC1" and "XYZ9" -- always three letters followed by a single digit. I want both parts of the label to increment logically, and always be the exact format and length.

I started with:

```
sequence(:code) { |n| "ABC#{n}" }
```

That was fine, but after the ninth label (`ABC9`) it went to (`ABC10`), violating my formatting, and only producing 10 (or 9?) values.

A quick fix of using the sequence for the letters and hard-coding one digit makes my rollover problem not occur for `26^3 => 17,576` instances, which *might* be okay. But, I really want some variability in the digit as well. A random digit would probably be good enough...but I want *all* the available values.

I thought about a few somewhat kludgy ways of building the string from one or two sequences to get comprehensive values always matching the format, but they seemed clunky.

Is there an elegant way in FactoryBot to build a sequenced string with a fixed-width letter segment followed by a fixed-width numeric segment that produces all possible values?

Comment: More generally, you can see it as a 4-digit number with 3 digits in base-26 (A-Z) and 1 digit in base-10 (0-9), i.e. "ABC9" can be interpreted as 0₂₆1₂₆2₂₆9₁₀ which would be 289 in decimal (0+260+20+9). To generate the sequence format from an integer you can use `divmod`, pretty much like converting seconds to HH:MM:SS.

Answer (score 5):

Just Ruby; no rails or whatever:

```
code = "AAA0"
20.times{ puts code.succ! }
```

Comment: Thanks for this insight, @steenslag . I suspect that FactoryBot uses `succ!` internally in its sequences.

Comment: Ruby 2.7 introduced `Enumerator::produce` which makes this even easier. e.g `enum = Enumerator.produce("AAA0",  &:succ)` then each time you need a new value `enum.next` need 20 values `enum.take(20)` etc.

Answer (score 4):

As it turns out, the solution in a factory is sublimely simple and graceful:

```
sequence(:code, 'AAA1')
```

This produces the following sequence:

```
FactoryBot.build :code

 => #<Code code: "AAA1">
 => #<Code code: "AAA2">
 => #<Code code: "AAA3">
 => #<Code code: "AAA4">
 => #<Code code: "AAA5">
 => #<Code code: "AAA6">
 => #<Code code: "AAA7">
 => #<Code code: "AAA8">
 => #<Code code: "AAA9">
 => #<Code code: "AAB0">
 => #<Code code: "AAB1">
 => #<Code code: "AAB2">
... four hours later ...
 => #<Code code: "ZZY7">
 => #<Code code: "ZZY8">
 => #<Code code: "ZZY9">
 => #<Code code: "ZZZ0">
 => #<Code code: "ZZZ1">
 => #<Code code: "ZZZ2">
 => #<Code code: "ZZZ3">
 => #<Code code: "ZZZ4">
 => #<Code code: "ZZZ5">
 => #<Code code: "ZZZ6">
 => #<Code code: "ZZZ7">
 => #<Code code: "ZZZ8">
 => #<Code code: "ZZZ9">
 => #<Code code: "AAAA0">
 => #<Code code: "AAAA1">
```

For my needs, I'm not concerned about the total rollover after 175,760 values.

It's also worth noting that you can start each segment wherever you like. This works just as well:

```
sequence(:code, 'ABC9')


FactoryBot.build :code

 => #<Code code: "ABC9">
 => #<Code code: "ABD0">
 => #<Code code: "ABD1">
```